# How much distance is there between electrons in an electron shell?

Tags: atoms

I imagine they would need keep a certain distance away from each other.

Comment: which shell, for which atoms?

Answer (score 2):

Electrons don't have a well-defined location within the atom (their wavefunctions are dispersed around the nucleus) so there's also not really a way to define the distance between them either. That said, electrons cannot be in the exact same wavefunction with the same spin as another electron, due to the Pauli Exclusion Principle, and there are only a finite number of allowed wavefunctions whose average position is within a given distance of the nucleus. This means that the atom does get bigger as more and more electrons are added, as electrons begin occupying higher-energy wavefunctions that are further from the nucleus.

It turns out that determining the specific size of an atom with a given number of electrons is actually a daunting problem. A very preliminary and pretty wrong estimate can be made by assuming that the electrons are all non-relativistic and also "ignore each other" except for following the Pauli Exclusion Principle (I would like to stress that these are **bad** assumptions). Then the size of an atom with atomic number $Z$ in row $n$ of the periodic table would be given by Bohr's approximation: $r=n^2\frac{a_0}{Z}$, where $a_0=0.53$ angstroms. Real atoms deviate quite significantly from this naïve estimate, for a few reasons. First, electrons don't actually ignore each other; the electrical repulsion between each electron and the others distorts the size and shape of each wavefunction. The repulsion also partially screens the attraction from the nucleus in the outer regions, which inflates the outer wavefunctions significantly (this is commonly referred to as the "shielding effect"). Finally, in large atoms, the outer electrons are actually energetic enough to be relativistic, which significantly changes the allowed wavefunctions. All of this has the effect of making the actual size of an atom difficult to compute from first principles; currently there is no analytical way to do so.